Why does readthedocs require authorisation to write commits when connecting to github?
I'm trying to use readthedocs with a github repo that stores a Python project. When I try to connect it to my github profile, I am asked to authorise the following:

This application will be able to read and write commit statuses (no direct code access).

It shouldn't need to change anything in my github repo. Can someone explain this?

Commit status is not the same thing as a commit: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses?apiVersion=2022-11-28
I suspect readthedocs would like to make a commit as "published" or something like that.

@JoachimSauer Oh that makes sense. Thanks!

Read the Docs requires "Commit status" permissions to be able to report build status on the pull request you open in your repository. You can read the whole documentation about this in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pull-requests.html
